# Injecting key events and motion events in android

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity, android-softkeyboard

Can anyone tell me on injecting key and motion events to same application as well as to other applications in android. Please note that it should work in market devices(Non rooted phones) as well. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

> Can anyone tell me on injecting key and motion events... to other applications in android. Please note that it should work in market devices(Non rooted phones) as well.

This is not possible, sorry.